# Table of Contents and pagination in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

I frequently create documents in Word 2010 that I want to print two-sided in book style, with mirrored margins and odd pages on the right. I want the 1-page Table of Contents to be an un-numbered "odd" page, blank on the back, so that the document starts with Page 1 on the right side, backed by Page 2. I tried using a section break, but that causes an extra blank side that isn't visible on the two-page view. It's an unwelcome surprise then that Page 1 prints as the "back" of the extra blank. Alternatively, without the manually added section break, P. 1 prints on the back of the Table of Contents.
Help!

Answer (score 1):

From [someone else](http://www.techtalkz.com/ms-office-help/29282-how-can-i-force-retain-section-break-odd-page.html) having the same type of issue,

> First, you should enable "Different odd and even" and/or "Mirror margins" in
>   Page Setup.
>   Then, instead of deleting any existing section breaks, just place the
>   insertion point in the section and then choose the desired "Section start"
>   on the Layout tab of the Page Setup dialog box.